# Restrict to use a class as a type in another class in c#

Tags: c#, oop

I have a class

```
abstract class EmployeeBase
{
}
```

I want that this `EmployeeBase` should not be used as a property in any of my other classes. Only a class derived from `EmployeeBase` can be used to declare a property in any other class. Is it possible to achieve that? If so, how?

Comment: You can't, basically. Why do you *want* to? The whole point of inheritance is that you *can* use the abstract class - a lot of code wouldn't need to depend on the implementation used.

Comment: While working on EF Code first approach, I want to avoid the field being created for the base class. I want only the inherited class to be used in creating the table.

Comment: So make sure you do that yourself. You could always write tests to check for this by reflection if you really want - but there's nothing in the language.

Comment: Whilst there is nothing stopping you from say creating `class MissPiggy { EmployeeBase Golly {get;set;} }`, VS will compile it quite happily, you'll have to detect it either with [nDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) on your DEV machine or on your CI/gated checkin box.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create instance of abstract class so there will be no variable or property created as `EmployeeBase`

You have to inherit from `EmployeeBase` so I believe your problem is already solved ;)

```
public abstract class EmployeeBase{}
public class Employee: EmployeeBase{}
class SomeClass
{
    public EmployeeBase Employee { get; set; }
    SomeClass()
    {
        Employee = new Employee(); // OOP in play :)
        Employee = new EmployeeBase(); // Error CS0144  
        // Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'EmployeeBase'
    }
}
```

Comment: @MickyD Nope. Author wants `Only a class derived from EmployeeBase can be used` and this is the case.

Comment: Oh didn't see that.  OP is weird

Answer (score 0):

You can get close to this this by making `EmployeeBase` a `protected` subclass of the class you wish to derive from:

```
public class OuterClass
{
    protected abstract class EmployeeBase { /*...*/ }
}
```

However, keep in mind this will prevent any properties of type `EmployeeBase` from being exposed as `public` or `internal`, since you can't expose an object with a less exposed type, since any consuming code wouldn't know the signature of the object. **EDIT** You could, however, expose them by `interface` or other base type.

While you can restrict inheritance from `EmployeeBase` by making all constructors `internal`, restricting use of a type is not well supported in C#, and raises many questions about what exactly you're trying to do.